# auto-resize image with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, autoresize

I have a .png images with transparent background.

I would like to auto-resize them to remove empty areas on the sides in command line, is it possible with ImageMagick?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using the [`-trim`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim) operator. Typical usage:

```
convert image.png -trim +repage image_trimmed.png
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And it also possible with mogrify, for multiple images.